# LaTeX package for Stackrel without AMSTeX

Tags: amsmath, stack, amstex

The [section 2.1 of this Wikibook chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Above_and_below) on LaTex states: `Without AmsTex the same result of \overset can be obtained with \stackrel`. But I've not been able to use Stackrel without amsmath package. Is there any package just specific to Stackrel? I want to compare the display of an expression in Stackrel environment with and without amsmath package.

**Update**
Never mind, it was my mistake. I realized it by reading response from Ulrike Fischer. I was using

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\quad \text{stackrel: } \stackrel{A}{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The terminology in the wikibook is out of date: What's being referred to as `AMSTeX` has been called `amsmath` just about everywhere else for years and years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\stackrel` works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
 $\stackrel{j}{=}$
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never mind, I was using `\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
$\quad \text{stackrel: }    \stackrel{A}{x}$
 \end{document}` Use of quad was the issue.